# Tree of Savior - level can't keep up with zones

Tags: tree-of-savior

I started playing Tree of Savior as Cleric (then advanced to Krivis). I am at level 28, but main quest is in zones for 39. Why am I progressing that fast, but my level is down? I am using all of my EXP cards immediately.

Comment: My friend has been suggesting I level up normally but only use my exp cards when I need to level quickly (and just gain normal exp otherwise). Also it is a Korean MMO, so the never ending grind is kind of a staple, so it might not be anything in particular. Just the way things are maybe?

Comment: i aggree. Grinding is a main part of point-&-click MMO

Comment: You can grind by either killing mob on your level or do repeatable quest .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many guides on the web who explain how to level up efficiently, but here are the basics for me:

You have two ways to level up :

- Grind : you need to find a good spots of monsters who are near your level, and kill them in a loop until you level up.
- Quests : you can do all the quests available at your level and collect the exp cards rewards.
  I think you missed all the quests from the second starter area (either Klaipeda or Orsha depending where you have started),
  there is two chains of main quests in each area and they will gradually take you to the next area with more secondary quests.
  You don't want to use all your exp cards on the spot if you plan to do questing because it will result of a low exp gain from monster with lower level than you (you practicly gain nothing from 10 underleveled monsters) so you will only use them when you start to fall under level.

Here is a map representing the order in which you have to complete each map:
[image: Tree of savior quest level map]

You should explore all the maps to 100% because Lena/Rena in Klaipeda gives you EXP cards depending on which map you explore. You also gain EXP cards from killing an X amount of monsters.